# How to pass Texture2D object into a shader program in cocos2d-x v3.1?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, shader

I am using cocos2d-x v3.1.

On each render cycle, my game does some off screen rendering onto a `RenderTexture` object.

Now, how do I pass the rendered texture (`Texture2D`) from the `RenderTexture` object into a shader (fragment) program as a sampler2D uniform?

The documentation does not seem to say much about the use of shaders in cocos2d-x v3.1.